# Пытаюсь обновить данные столбца в базе данных (MySQL)

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть строчка:

```
<tr data-id="32"><td id="czy-przeczytane"><a href="pytanie.php?id=32">I wrote the code in Java, but it does not work, I need help</a></td><td>Java</td><td>12-06-2021</td><td class="color-autor">vladyslav11</td></tr>
```

У меня есть файл с обновлением столбца `przeczytane` на `1` так как он типа  `boolean`:

```
<?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "serwisdlaprogramistow";

                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }

                

                $sql_update = "UPDATE pytania SET przeczytane = '1' WHERE id={$_POST["id"]}";

                if ($conn->query($sql_update) === TRUE) {
                echo "Successful update";
                } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                }

                    $conn->close();
                ?>
```

И у меня есть скрипт который должен обновлять столбец в таблице в базе данных:

```
$("#czy-przeczytane").click(function(){
    $(this).load("pytanie_czy_przeczytane.php", { id: $(this).parent().data("id") });
})
```

И это не работает... буду рад как всегда любым подсказкам :)

Comment: А что значит "не работает", что возвращает load, не видно ли каких ошибок в вкладке network консоли браузера. Там же посмотреть а действительно ли был передан правильный id. Вы бы вывели что нибудь в случае успешного update

Comment: У меня нечего не пишет в нетворке, я просто перехочу по строчке и все

Comment: Как это ничего, запрос же должен проходить. Он что возвращает, 200 код хотя бы

Comment: 200 код есть, да

Comment: Ну значит ошибок нет. поэтому и предлагаю вывести что нибудь полезное в случае успешного update, например количество обновленных записей https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.affected-rows.php И заодно вывести id который был при этом применен. Ведь update не даст никаких ошибок если id окажется несуществующим, но и ничего не обновит

Comment: Когда я убираю условие WHERE и перехожу в строке браузера к файл у обновлением, то обновляются все строчки, а так по клику на строку ничего не происходит

Comment: Ну так значит точно в where попадает id которого нет в таблице вот он ничего и не обновляет. смотрите какой id передан. начиная с вкладки network, там внизу видно все данные что в post были переданы

Comment: Оказывается я забыл добавить $(document).ready(function() {}), я даже не думал что без этого оно не будет работать... Я плачу...